# Is it possible to create a button in Rails with the geocoder gem that fetches a user's current location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I'd like to create a simple app where locations can be saved from a user's current location and distances can be calculated between these locations. Can this be done with the following code:

```
geocoded_by :ip_address,
  :latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lon
after_validation :geocode
```

Comment: rather than location by ip address, you should use HTML5 geolocation in the browser and pass that info to the server, it's more dependable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this

Comment: @maxpleaner Do you know how accurate HTML5 geolocation is? Would I be able to get lat long data to within a few meters?

Comment: yeah, it is pretty accurate. If you've ever seen a website that prompts you "allow this website to know your location" and then it plots your exact location on a map ... that's how it's done. Lat/lng coords is exactly what HTML5 geolocation gives you, in fact.